# Error "Number of subjects must be greater than 3" with rmcorr( ) but I have 48 subjects?

Tags: r, correlation

this one has been eating up my morning. Using package rmcorr, function rmcorr with args

rmcorr(participant, measure1, measure2, dataset, CIs = c("analytic",
  "bootstrap"), nreps = 100, bstrap.out = F)

```
head(Snapretest)
rmcorr('ParticipantID', 'Snap1', 'Snap2', Snapretest)

head(Snapretest)
  ParticipantID Snap1 Snap2
1         11682     9     9
2         11683     6     6
3         11684    41    46
4         11685    12    14
5         11687    30    41
6         11689    17    20

Error in psych::r.con(rmcorrvalue, errordf) : 
  number of subjects must be greater than 3
```

I have 48 subjects in Snapretest? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the example provided in the documentation they don't quote their variable names.  Try removing the quotes.

Comment: So I had the data set up incorrectly - I know have it set up in long form, which it requires, but I do not understand why I need a second measure then? I just want to do a repeated measures correlation between time 1 SnapYes and time 2 SnapYes.